# Ng-repeat on wrapper of multiple options inside <select> cause the options to receive null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

so what I want to accomplish is populating a select element with a recurisve json, like so:

```
[{
  "siteId": 1,
  "name": "Test 1",
  "siteTypeId": 2,
  "childSites": [
    {
      "siteId": 3,
      "name": "Test 3",
      "siteTypeId": 2,
      "childSites": [
        {
          "siteId": 2,
          "name": "Test 2",
          "siteTypeId": 2,
          "childSites": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "siteId": 4,
      "name": "Test 4",
      "siteTypeId": 2,
      "childSites": []
    }
  ]
}]
```

I found two ways I could approach this, either converting the structred object into a flat array, and then using ngOptions, or using the following code (which include ng-repeat with a custom template)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sites-template">
    <!--The object itself-->
    <option>{{item.name}}</option>

    <!--child items (if any), recursive call -->
    <div ng-if="item.childSites && item.childSites.length > 0"
         ng-repeat="item in item.childSites"
         ng-include="sites-template">
    </div>
</script>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <div ng-repeat="site in sites" ng-include="sites-template"></div>
</select>
```

But when I run it with the json supplied above, it result with an empty select, can anyone explain why does it happen? I guess the correct solution would be to flattend the structured object, but I'm curious...

It seems that applying ng-repeat on an element inside a select tag, the child of the element would not recieve the value (when I removed the select tag it worked, as well of removing the wrapper and applying the ng-repeat straight on the option element, without the template), why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: So just for clarification, you're saying that ng-repeat on a select gives you one blank option? Or that the blank option is an element of the array that is getting nulled out?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it produces an empty select (no elements at all).

Comment: Try something more like this: <select class="form-control" id="categoryUpdateList" multiple="multiple" size="10" name="categoryUpdateList"
                                ng-options="p.toString() for p in viewModel.selectedProducts" ng-model="viewModel.selectedOptions"></select>

Basically, don't use ng-repeat on the div, use ng-options on the select.

Comment: And if you need to nest in the select for some reason like that, use option, not div.

Comment: And one more thing that would help I think, can you copy the generated html from the select list and put it in your question?

Comment: sites should be an array if you want to use it in a ng-repeat

Comment: I use div as a wrapper (purely for applying the template), I don't want nested options, I need **flat list**, and while not perfect, div doesn't seem to affect the elements at all, just easier to group that way (if I build a select with multiple divs, each containing mutliple options, the result would be the same a flat list of options).
And I'm using **bootstrap-select** plugin, so I need to conform to their api.

I have a solution (flat the array out before sending it to ng-repeat), but I do want to know why this happens...

Comment: div is not a logical child of a select. What do you think a div inside a select should look like?